# Globbing pattern not working in my script

Tags: python, linux, bash, automation, devops

I have a script with a simple globbing pattern to create multiple files and it works just as
I want it to.
The problem arises when I use the `at` command to schedule the running of the script.
Somehow, the script creates only one file instead of the many files it should create.

This is the code below:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir folder1

touch folder1/file{1..100}.txt
```

This somehow creates only `file{1..100}.txt` in the folder1 directory instead of a hundred files.

Output when I schedule the script to run at any given time:

```
  stevis@stevis:~/Desktop/Linux/bash/scheduling$ ls folder1/
  file{1..100}.txt
```

Comment: Looks like it is being executed with `/bin/sh`, not `bash`. How are you scheduling your script with `at`?

Comment: `at` runs `sh`, not `bash`. You even get a warning when you run it.

Comment: Mind, if you tell `at` to invoke your script _as an executable_, the shebang will be honored and it'll run with bash anyhow; but the details of how you're doing that invocation matter. If you don't show us exactly how you run `at`, this isn't answerable.

Comment: (btw, how/why is this tagged python?)

Comment: MAybe problema can showup due to en error in the folder creation. Make shure you cleanup previous directory: `rm -rf folder1`. I also suggest `mkdir -p folder1`

Comment: The problem was that /bin/sh file was linked to dash. Running this command confirmed it;  file -h /bin/sh. So i changed it to bash using this command sudo ln -sf bash /bin/sh and it worked. Thank you all for your prompt response.